# Find coordinates of searched value in 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to search for a letter and store it's coordinates in two different variables.  All of the methods I have found can successfully find the value, but they don't mention anything about the coordinates.

```
TAP_CODE = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
            ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
            ['L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'],
            ['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'],
            ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

The idea is to convert the coordinates into a string of dots separated by a space which indicate the tap code. Ex: '.. ...' for H, '.... ..' for R

Comment: Can u post what did u try?

Comment: I don't exactly know what to try, I have found a lot of ways to search for the value, but none that really have anything to do with the list coordinate it lives at. All they do is check to see if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> TAP_CODE = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
            ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
            ['L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'],
            ['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'],
            ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]

>>> def f(l, ch):
    for i,sub_list in enumerate(l):
        if ch in sub_list:
            print ('.'*(i+1),' ', '.'*(sub_list.index(ch)+1))

>>> f(TAP_CODE, 'H')
..   ...
>>> f(TAP_CODE, 'R')
....   ..
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple if you make your `TAP_CODE` into a `numpy.ndarray`. Then you can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the coordinates:

```
In [15]: TAP_CODE = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
        ['L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'],
        ['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'],
        ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']])

In [16]: np.where(TC=='R')
Out[16]: (array([3]), array([1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it:

```
def get_coordinates(letter):
  for i in range(len(TAP_CODE)):
    if letter in TAP_CODE[i]:
      x = i
      y = TAP_CODE[i].index(letter)
  return x, y

>>> get_coordinates('M')
(2, 1)
```

Add `+1` to x and y inside the function if you don't want to use 0 as index.

Answer (score 0):

How I'd handle it...

in python 3.5

```
def dots(matrix, target):
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
        for t in range(len(matrix[1])):
            if TAP_CODE[i][t] == target:
                coords = (i+1,t+1)
    for i in range(coords[0]):
        print('.', end="")

    print(' ', end="")
    for t in range(coords[1]):
        print('.', end="")


dots(TAP_CODE, 'H')
```

output

```
.. ...
```

perhaps not the most *pythonic* way, but a way to approach it without bringing in anything unnecessary, which I think keeps things unambiguous :^)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by traversing through TAP_CODE. For the sake of this example lets assume you are searching for the character 'H'.

```
desired = 'H'
xCord,yCord = -1,-1 # placeholder values
for y in range(len(TAP_CODE)): # traverse through all lists
    for x in range(len(TAP_CODE[y]): # traverse through all elements in all lists
        if(TAP_CODE[y][x] == desired): # if element is what I want
            xCord, yCord = x,y
```

The only issue is that for instance if we search for 'A', and its coordinates are (1,1), this will return (0,0), because lists start at 0. You can remedy this by adding 1 to both xCord and yCord after you have found them.

```
xCord += 1
yCord += 1
```

If you want to convert xCord and yCord to their lengths in periods, you can use this:

```
example = 5
exampleString = "." * example
print(exampleString) -> "....."
```

I hope this helps Prof Plum. Good luck!